# how to boot into Windows 7 if I only have grub now

Tags: boot, grub2

My laptop is installed with window 7, now I want to install ubuntu using its ISO image and easyBCD, however, I failed in installing ubuntu, and when I boot the laptop I can only see grub interface.

Now how can I boot into WINDOWS7 using grub command?

I tried

```
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader +1
boot
```

however, I can only return to "Install Ubuntu" , I think the reason is that I put the initrd.lz vmlinuz in drive C(where windows7 is installed)

now I have a ubuntu8 CD.
I insert the CD and want to use the TRIAL version to delete "initrd.lz" and "vmlinuz" in C drive, but I simply can't enter /dev/sda and /dev/sda1. Should I install ubuntu 8 and then modify GRUB under ubuntu 8 so that I can start window7?

Answer (score 0):

You must restore the hard disk mbr.

Boot with a live-cd.

Download at:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ms-sys/

The file:
ms-sys-2.2.0.tar.gz

Open a terminal.

Execute:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/Downloads
tar -xzvf ms-sys-2.2.0.tar.gz
cd ms-sys
make
sudo su
make install
ms-sys --mbr7 /dev/sda
```

For write a Windows 7 MBR to device.

This program is used to create Microsoft compatible boot records.

It is able to do the same as Microsoft "fdisk /mbr" to a hard disk.

It is also able to do the same as Microsoft "sys d:" to a floppy or FAT partition except that it does not copy any system files, only the boot record is written.

Comment: I installed ubuntu, and I notice my windows7 is in /media/lily, now I tried: ```ms-sys --mbr7 /media/lily/```, but I get
```Unable to open /media/lily/, Is a directory```, how to deal with this?